# How to fix caching issue in PHP data from database in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to use the code below for my plugin development but there is a caching issue (I think). Please below for the details.

**Problem**

I created a filter to accept the customized url, and I'm querying the database but it seems like the result value is not changing in the browser but changing in the database. So basically the data passed is not returning the updated value from the database.

**Code**

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('coupon/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?coupon=$matches[1]', 'top');
});

add_filter('query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'coupon';
    return $query_vars;
});

add_action( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'coupon' ) == false || get_query_var( 'coupon' ) == '' ) {
        return $template;
    }

    ob_clean();
    ob_start();

    // Check if coupon exists
    global $wpdb;
    $coupon = get_query_var('coupon');

    $coupon_query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_urls WHERE coupon = %s AND claimed_at IS NULL', $coupon);
    $coupon_available = $wpdb->query($coupon_query) ? true : false;

    if(!$coupon_available) {
        header('Location: /'); // Redirect to landing page
        exit();
    }
    
    return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'views/client/index.php';;
} );
```

**Expected Result**

The expected result should redirect the user to the `header('Location: /');` if the coupon is not available.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you flash your rewrite rules?

Comment: @KodeFor.Me Sorry Im new in plugin development . How can I do that? And why do we need to flash it?

Comment: The routes creation is an expensive process in WordPress, and for that reason, the WordPress it caching all the routes once and then it is using them all the time.

The simplest way to flash the routes, is to go in the WordPress Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and just save your current settings.

Every time you save permalinks settings, the WordPress re-generates the Routes. This way, will track your custom route along with the other routes of the WordPress.

Comment: @KodeFor.Me Still not working with that solution.

Comment: @Jonjie Just try to print some thing twice or thrice on the page where you getting cache issue. It will remove the cache because wordpress version cache could be an issue.

Comment: I tried it at the top, and tried it at the bottom of the page but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need update the permalinks in the WordPress admin area. For example:

```
Step 1: In the WordPress admin area, go to `Settings > Permalinks`
Step 2: Click `Save Changes`
Step 3: Permalinks and rewrite rules are flushed.
```

Comment: Not working. Basically, when you visit `/coupon/CODE123` url, it will return a from, so when you submit the form, it will run the update query. I think the browser is caching the page or the url; Im not 100% sure, but based on my code above, if the sql condition does not met, the user must be redirected in the home page. But the problem is, it is not redirecting even if the query condition does not met. But when I check the database table, it is updating there.

Comment: @Jonjie maybe you should use another hook for example `teplate_redirect`?

Comment: `template_redirect` is also not working. The page returns `The page isn’t redirecting properly`